# Does a software service pack install to the machines system files, or to the applications files

Tags: macos, mac, powerpc, vectorworks

Ive got a copy of vectorworks 2008 that ive installed on my mac running osx 10.8.2. The installer for vectorworks 2008 is a power pc application (but the actual vectorworks software isnt) so it can run but cant be installed.

So as a work around i installed it onto an old machine, and then copied across the application folder from user/name/applications and put it on the new machine.

This all worked fine and the program runs, but it needs an update to the latest service pack to add a couple of features, i downloaded it but of course the service pack installer is a power pc app

What i was wandering is would the same technique (ie. installing it on an old machine and copying it across) work for the service pack ?

Are the service packs installed to the application folder or are they installed to the system files ?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just try it?

Comment: ive since upgraded my 'old machine' machines os so id have to downgrade it again to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed updates on Mac OS X 10.7.5 last month via the AutoUpdater of Vectorworks on one user account. When starting the Vectorworks on another there was an error, which disappeared after updating in this account also. So it looks like that it is not system-based.

Comment: @Kazark, ive experimented with it a bit and it seems to be application based, i moved it from one machine to another just by copying the application/vectorworks folder (mac) and the service pack came along with it so it does seem to be application based.